# ArrayList only display 1 item in SharedPreferences

Tags: android, android-fragments, sharedpreferences

I have 3 fragments.

1st fragment is used to display a Listview.

2nd fragment is to display what the user has clicked in 1st fragment follow by a button(add to cart).

3rd fragment is used to display the total number of products being added to cart.

**I have added many times of the different products, however, it only display the last item being added to cart, the rest products didn't show in the listview**

**display_listview.java**

```
public class display_listview extends Fragment {

String[] mobileArray = {"Android","IPhone","WindowsMobile","Blackberry","WebOS","Ubuntu","Windows7","Max OS X"};

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_display_listview, container, false);

    ListView listView = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.lv);
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mobileArray);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {


            String product_name=adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();

            product_details my_alert=new product_details();
            my_alert.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(),"");

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("name",product_name);
            my_alert.setArguments(bundle);

        }
    });

    Button get_button=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.cart);
    get_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            FragmentManager manager=getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
            my_cart list=new my_cart();
            transaction.replace(R.id.top,list);
            transaction.addToBackStack("wtf");
            transaction.commit();
        }
    });
    return v;
}
}
```

**show_product.java**

```
public class show_product extends DialogFragment {

LayoutInflater inflater;
View v;
ArrayList<String> products_clicked=new ArrayList<String>();

public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    inflater=getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_product_details,null);

    TextView get_text=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.text);

    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    final String name= bundle.getString("name");
    get_text.setText(name);

    AlertDialog.Builder build=new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    build.setView(v).setPositiveButton("Add to cart", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

            SharedPreferences preferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("order_list", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor=preferences.edit();

            products_clicked.add(name);
            Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
            set.addAll(products_clicked);

            editor.putStringSet("yourKey", set);
            editor.commit();

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),name +" has added to cart.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    return build.create();

}
}
```

**my_cart.java**

```
public class my_cart extends Fragment {


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_cart, container, false);

    SharedPreferences preferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("order_list", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    Set<String> set = preferences.getStringSet("yourKey", null);
    List<String> sample=new ArrayList<String>(set);
    ArrayAdapter adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, sample);
    ListView listView1 = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView1.setAdapter(adapter1);

    return v;
}
}
```

Please refer to the screenshot

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you're calling show_product in your display_listview class? I can only see product_details is used to show an alert?

Comment: On to a different topic, name of a java class must start with upper case letter.

Comment: i dont get what do you mean but so far my coding is ok except the problem i mentioned above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the `product_clicked` is an instance variable and does not keep your previously added items.

Modify the `onClick()` method in `show_product` class like this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i)
{
    SharedPreferences preferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("order_list", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor=preferences.edit();

    Set<String> set = preferences.getStringSet("yourKey", new HashSet<String>());
    set.add(name);

    editor.putStringSet("yourKey", set);
    editor.commit();

    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),name +" has added to cart.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

As you can see, we fetch the previously saved set in `SharedPreferences`, add the new item and store it again.

Comment: thx! after changing to what you have suggested, it works but another problem comes out. If i close the apps and restart again, when i view "My Cart" for the first time, it always show "WindowsMobile" for the first item( I didn't click add to cart). Any idea whats going on?

Comment: `SharedPreferences` saves data permanently. It is there, because in previous launches, you have added that to cart. Isn't that what you want? If you don't want data to be stored for next launches, then don't use `SharedPreferences` at all. Use your previous code, but make `products_clicked` static.

Comment: ok. btw, just wondering if I have use the correct method of doing shopping cart? I wanna save the item in cart by using SharedPreferences .

Comment: Saving in SharedPreferences is OK. Another solution is to use sqlite database.